# When I run the code below it appears to to be showing incorrect number of binding supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 6 supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def search(name="", address="",phone_number="",no_of_days="",room_types="",total=""):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("hot.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM hot WHERE name=? OR address=? OR phone_number=? OR room_type=? OR total=?",(name, address, phone_number, no_of_days, room_types, total))
```

When I try clicking a search button on the GUI the error above appears. I don't know what am Missing out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please format the code in your question. But I don't understand what's unclear about this message. You have 5 placeholders and try to fill in 6 values.

Answer (score 0):

As Matthias already mentioned, you are missing the 6th placeholder. Specifically, you'll need to add `OR no_of_days = ?` since you provide 6 values but only 5 placeholders in your query.

Comment: Thanks just seeing it now. Much appreciated